# Creating a "virtual" RAID 0 on top of two drives in Windows?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, raid

I would like a very fast area for large files to be stored quickly across multiple drives (preferably temporarily). It would be like how a RAM disk takes up memory until you disable it, but across two hard drives.

The use case is for recording video game footage and the space needed is more than any reasonable amount of RAM could handle, and the bandwidth of one drive is too slow. I figure I can store more frames with a faster speed.

EDIT: I would like it to be on top of two drives that are already in use and have data on them. The easiest solution I can think of now is a VM running Windows 7 with a software RAID inside of it, where the two files for the drive are on separate physical drives. Unfortunately that has a lot of overhead.

I already have two HDD's, so I was planning on just doing something with them before buying any additional hardware.

Comment: How fast do you need?  SATA 3 or 6g SSD offer 500mb/s is that not enough?

Comment: What bandwidth do you think you need, and why?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can create a software RAID, in windows and remove it all you want from the device manager.  However, the drives will be erased every time you create it.

Better options:

1 SATA 6g offering 500-550mb/s should be enough.  If not you can get 2 ssd, and make a software RAID in windows for speeds of 1000-1100mb/s

M2 SSD with NVMe offer speeds approx 2gb/s speed as do pci-e x16 ssd.

Comment: Could I make a software RAID on drives that already have one partition on them with data? Could I shrink them and make two new partitions that have RAID-0?

Comment: Say you had 2 hdd, 500gb.  You could create a 800gb softward RAID 0 by combine 400gb x 2.  The last 100gb you could partition anyway.  However, you would have to setup it up, the first time with a 2 blank drives.  This seems like a huge effort compared to an SSD which is like 5 hdd in a software RAID 0